# Icons on jquery-steps "Next" and "Previous" Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wizard, jquery-steps

I'm using jquery-steps on a project. But i can't find any way to add an icon to the Previous or Next buttons.

I modified the javascript with the following code:

```
                            labels: {
                            next: "&raquo;",
                            previous: "&laquo;"
                        }
```

But this is not what I like.

this is the plugin url: http://www.jquery-steps.com/

Someone knows a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to inject the html to the button using jquery. Try this:

```
$('a[href="#next"]').html($('a[href="#next"]').html()+'&raquo;');
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

```
labels: {
         next: '\u00bb',
         previous: '\u00ab'
}
labels: {
         next: String.fromCharCode(187),
         previous: String.fromCharCode(171)
}
labels: {
         next: '»',
         previous: '«'
}
//String.fromCharCode(187) » '\u00bb'
//String.fromCharCode(171) « '\u00ab'
```